# Make a query in mysql without invoking a trigger (How to disable a trigger)

Tags: mysql, triggers, myisam

I have 2 tables: `comments` and `comments_likes`.

---

**comments**

```
id     
message
likes
```

**triggers**:

*AFTER DELETE*

```
DELETE FROM comments_likes WHERE comment_id = OLD.id;
```

---

**comments_likes**

```
id        
comment_id
```

**triggers**:

*AFTER INSERT*

```
UPDATE comments SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE comments.id = NEW.comment_id;
```

*AFTER DELETE*

```
UPDATE comments SET likes = likes - 1 WHERE comments.id = OLD.comment_id;
```

*AFTER UPDATE*

```
**omited code, updates comments**
```

---

So the question is, **can I disable the triggers when activating them from another trigger**?

What I want is do something likes this:

*AFTER DELETE*

```
IF NOT called_from_another_trigger() THEN
    UPDATE comments SET likes = likes - 1 WHERE comments.id = OLD.comment_id;
END IF;
```

**[EDIT]**

A non optimized solution would be (very slow query... makes a query for each LIKE register):

```
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT id FROM comments WHERE comments.id = OLD.comment_id) THEN
        UPDATE comments SET comments.cache_likes = comments.cache_likes - 1 WHERE comments.id = OLD.comment_id;
    END IF;
END
```

UPDATE `LOW PRIORITY` and `IGNORE` don't works.

**[EDIT 2]**

I have another idea, is possible to set a global variable in the first trigger and read it from the other trigger?

Ex:

first trigger:

```
@disable_triggers = true;
// do the stuff that calls another triggers
@disable_triggers = false;
```

other trigger:

```
if @disable_triggers = false then
    // do the stuff
end if;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To disable triggers you can do:

**Trigger 1**

```
SET @disable_trigger = 1;
// do stuff that calls trigger 2
SET @disable_trigger = NULL;
```

**Trigger 2**

```
IF @disable_trigger IS NULL THEN
    // do stuff only if called from a query and not from trigger 1
END IF;
```

Comment: Ineresting! Can you actually disable triggers inside a trigger?

Comment: @Mchl: Yep, with this method you can :) @var are globals for the connection. You must use IS NULL because variables that haven't been defined are always NULL.

Comment: this helped me 4 years later! i was exactly looking for something like this. after 1 hour of googling and searching SO, i finally found your answer. it's so easy, but i never would have figured it out by myself. i am just not used to be able to "program" with mysql.

Comment: is this thread-safe ?

Answer (score 1):

Can be a bit ugly, but what i do is rename the table to table2 which the trigger does not attach too, and then, on the end, rename back.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. That's the point of triggers: to be run always.

<s>Besides, I can't see why you would need that in your case. At worst nothing gets updated - no errors will be raised.</s>

You can always add a condition in your trigger, to check if they (or part of their code) should be run (for example if there is a record in relevant table).

Comment: When you try to delete a comment, the trigger deletes all likes. When likes are deleted, they update the comment that has been deleted. A error message appears: `Can't update table 'comments' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger`

Comment: @Wiliam: Well, with a condition I can do it... but isn't the solution I was searching u.u

Comment: @Mchl maybe that is the point of the triggers, but in MySQL they aren't always executed. If a row is removed because of CASCADE foreign key constraint enforcement, no triggers are executed. Reference: [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). I strongly believe the roots of this limitation of MySQL have the same root reason as the error in William's comment.