# How to efficiently delete from table A that is joined with table B and table A has an after delete trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `products` table, a `category` table and a join-table to link the two, named `prod_cat_join`. I am attempting to periodically delete all categories not associated with a product with a specific team ID. Let it be known that `category` has a trigger that deletes all joins in `prod_cat_join` associated with a `category` after a category is deleted. Is there a single SQL query that can be invoked to delete all categories not associated with a product and is associated with a specific team ID without running into a function/trigger error?

The trigger goes as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dbe1`@`%` TRIGGER `db`.`category_AFTER_DELETE` AFTER DELETE ON `category` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
delete from prod_cat_join  where prod_cat_join.categoryID = ID;
END
```

And my query that is periodically called to delete all categories not associated with a product is:

```
DELETE db.category FROM db.category 
LEFT JOIN db.prod_cat_join AS join_cat 
ON join_cat.categoryID = db.category.ID 
WHERE join_cat.productID IS NULL AND db.category.teamID = '1234'
```

I know it's possible to query all categories not associated with a product then delete the returned set of unassociated categories. But that seems inefficient as it requires two queries. Given our current setup is it possible to bypass the trigger to run the aforementioned query? Or is there some other single query method to delete the unassociated categories? And would putting an after delete trigger in `prod_cat_join` to delete all categories who no longer have an association to a join be effective? Would that not end up invoking the above-mentioned deletion trigger?

Guidance would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a trigger instead of a foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598155/how-to-disable-triggers-in-mysql for how to temporarily disable the trigger using a global variable.

Comment: @Barmar As I've understand the reverse order of the adjacency is required.

Comment: I don't think so. `prod_cat_join` has a foreign key to `category`. When you delete from `category`, it deletes all the corresponding rows from `prod_cat_join`. That's what `ON DELETE CASCADE` does.

Comment: @Barmar But @HDubz want to delete `category` entries having no references in the   `join_cat` table. I think that another trigger for `join_cat` should delete the `category` with no `products`

Comment: Deleting all categories that have no associated join is probably not a good idea. It might just be a temporary condition.

Comment: @Kondybas I'm not suggesting that he should delete from `category` with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. I'm saying that the trigger that deletes from `prod_join_cat` should be done with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.